# How do I use a variable within the date command in shell?

Tags: shell

I've got a cURL command that gets a date and sets it to a variable as a string. But then I want to use that variable as a date so I use the date command on the variable but it seems like the date command doesn't like this. How do I go about setting this variable as a date?

Example:

```
date=$(curl blahblahblah)
echo $date
"2017-11-02T13:23:52+00:00"
date -d $date +%s
date: invalid date ‘"2017-11-02T13:23:52+00:00"’
```

When I substitute $date for the actual value, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output from `curl` has double quotes and your `date` variable has those quotes around the date value.

In `bash` you can do this to strip double quotes before using `date` command:

```
date -d "${date//\"/}" '+%s'
1509629032
```

If you don't have `bash` then use:

```
date -d $(echo "$date" | tr -d '\"') '+%s'
1509629032
```